Missing Data in Spreadsheet Editor
I'm following a Geometry Nodes tutorial from Entagma and I can't seem to get the Spreadsheet Editor to display any face data.
In the tutorial, the faces should have the attributes shade_smooth, material_index and normal.

No filters are applied in the editor
Object Evaluation State is set to Evaluated - although I've also
tried adding a viewer node to the end of the tree and selecting
Viewer Node
The object is selected in the Outliner
I'm using Blender 4.2, I believe the tutorial is in 3.1.




Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@Lutzi No absolutely I understand. This was one I couldn't find an answer with in Google so I thought I'd try my luck here. Seem to have angered a few people in doing so though! :s

Hello please continue the conversation in the chat

It is not only a matter of Blender version. Some information will only be displayed if it is relevant. The following example is using Blender 4.2 as well.
This is the default cube. It is shaded flat, and it only has the default material in the first material slot. This is the data the Spreadsheet shows in the Face domain (you do not even need a GN modifier for that):

All faces show that the attribute sharp_face is "true". Since all faces get the first material if there is no other present, nothing else is shown there.
Now I shade the cube smooth and add a second material to it:

No attribute columns are shown anymore. The reason is that all faces share the same data and it is 0 (0 for "false" in the sharp_face attribute, but also the index of the material slot).
Before that the sharp_face attribute column showed up because the value was "true" or 1.
Now I go into Edit Mode, select the front face and assign the second material to it. I also shade the face flat (yes, you can shade individual faces smooth or flat in Edit Mode):

Now there are two attribute columns: material_index and sharp_face. They appeared because both attributes got their data changed to something <> 0 by applying the second material to the face with index 4 and shading it flat. Notice that the columns appear in the order in which I change the attributes. If I would have shaded it flat first and then assigned the material, the columns would be flipped.
So much for the why there are attribute columns and which. Maybe there is even some way to get back the normal attribute like in the tutorial, but I do not know how. But they did not completely get rid of all previous attribute columns (well okay, shade_smooth was kind of inverted to sharp_face), they just made them disappear if a column does only contain 0 or "false" in all rows. And like this it is already present since at least version 3.6.9 as far as I can tell.
//EDIT: The following is a bit too much in-depth on how the materials work in Geometry Nodes and not really on-topic with the missing attributes, but since a bit of that looks seemingly wrong compared to what I described above where no Geometry Nodes are involved, I thought this might also be informative and show the differences:
If you are looking at the Spreadsheet when you have a Geometry Nodes modifier on the object, there is some difference regarding the material_index column.
Since original geometry coming from the Group Input can have its materials appplied directly, the column appears or not like explained earlier.
Geometry created within the nodetree does not have a default material and as soon as you give it a Set Material node, the material_index column appears and shows 0 by default, even if you have not chosen a material yet. This is not the first slot index of the base object, it is the first "virtual" slot of this new geometry reserved for "no material".
If you choose any material in the node, the material_index shows 1, meaning this is the virtual slot 1, not the empty slot 0. If you add another Set Material node, this will be slot 2. If you use the Selection input to give different faces different materials, the material_index column will show 0 for faces which get no material assigned, 1 for those who get a material with the first Set Material node and 1 for those getting a material from the second Set Material node etc.
And now the seemingly weird thing: of course you plug the original geometry into a Set Material node as well to override the original materials. If the object already has two materials in slot 0 and 1, then the Set Material node will automatically get the material_index 2 - a new yet to be chosen material. Only if you select one of the existing materials in slot 0 or 1 it will show their index.

Answered by @Lutzi

There is no issue, the only attribute by default is sharp_face which
doesn't survive the Set Shade Smooth node. The other attributes you
were talking about have changed since.
They all have their custom nodes now, i.e. Material Index and Normal
nodes.


The material_index attribute still exists.
